# How can I convert EditText to html without nesting specific tags

Tags: java, android, html, android-edittext

I use this code to convert the text of edittext to html

```java
    String html = Html.toHtml(edittext.getText);
```

But it keeps nesting tags. That's not my problem. But I don't want to nest some specific tags like `<img>`

For example, this is the text of EditText:

```
Hello how are you?
[Here's an image.]
```

Expected result:

```html
    <p dir="ltr">Hello how are you</p> 
    <img src="path/to/image">
```

But it gives me this:

```html
    <p dir="ltr">Hello how are you<br> <img src="path/to/image"> </p>
```

I don't want that `<img>` tag gets nested in the the `<p>`. Because I couldn't show the image later.
I just need to avoid only `<img>` gets nested. Not other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string before converting it by delimiter:

```
String getHtml = "<p dir="ltr">Hello how are you</p> <img src="path/to/image">"; 
String[] splitElements = getHtml.split("</p>");
```

And after that, you can pass both strings and convert those. They will be separate and non-nested.